# Laço repetição jquery

Tags: jquery

Caros, estou com um problemas e ainda não consegui encontrar uma solução, ainda sou novo em jquery, gostaria de uma pequena ajuda, por favor.
No codigo abaixo eu tenho um procedimento para chamar um dialog, o qual será carregado com uma tabela preenchida com o php. Essa tabela possui um campo input text para pesquisa e todas as linhas possuem um checkbox, para quando selecionado e o botão pressionado, o nome seja enviado para a pagina anterior. Tudo está funcionando perfeitamente, porém tenho q repetir o codigo 3 vezes, caso queira usar em 3 campos diferentes. Gostaria de saber como posso passar o id do botao clicado e a partir dele fazer um if e executar o procedimento. Deve ser algo simples, mas não consegui ainda. Obrigado

```
                <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){   
                $("#buttonP1").click(function() {getValueUsingClass1();});
                $("#buttonP2").click(function() {getValueUsingClass2();});
                $("#buttonP3").click(function() {getValueUsingClass3();});
                function getValueUsingClass1(){
                /* declare an checkbox array */
                var chkArray = [];
                /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
                $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                    chkArray.push($(this).val());
                });
                var teste = $(this).id;
                alert(teste);
                /* we join the array separated by the comma */
                var selected;
                selected = chkArray.join('') + "";

                /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
                if(selected.length > 1){
                    if(chkArray.length > 1){
                    alert("Selecione um campo");
                    $('input[id=TP_ACO_P]').val("");
                    }else{  
                    $('input[id=TP_ACO_P]').val(selected);}
                }else{
                    alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");  
                }
                $('input[id=buscar]').val("");
            }
                function getValueUsingClass2(){
                /* declare an checkbox array */
                var chkArray = [];

                /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
                $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                    chkArray.push($(this).val());
                });

                /* we join the array separated by the comma */
                var selected;
                selected = chkArray.join('') + "";

                /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
                if(selected.length > 1){
                    if(chkArray.length > 1){
                    alert("Selecione um campo");
                    $('input[id=ACAB_P]').val("");
                    }else{  
                    $('input[id=ACAB_P]').val(selected);}
                }else{
                    alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");  
                }
            }
                function getValueUsingClass3(){
                /* declare an checkbox array */
                var chkArray = [];

                /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
                $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
                    chkArray.push($(this).val());
                });

                /* we join the array separated by the comma */
                var selected;
                selected = chkArray.join('') + "";

                /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
                if(selected.length > 1){
                    if(chkArray.length > 1){
                    alert("Selecione um campo");
                    $('input[id=TT_P]').val("");
                    }else{  
                    $('input[id=TT_P]').val(selected);}
                }else{
                    alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");  
                }
                $('input[id=buscar]').val("");
            }
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                  height:400,
                  width:500,
                  modal: true,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  open: function(event, ui) {  
                    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none");  

                }

                });
                $( "#openerP1" ).click(function() {
                $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                  $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog( "open" );

                });
                $( "#buttonP1" ).click(function() {
                  $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog( "close" );
                });
              });
            $(function(){$("#dialogP1").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();});

            $(function() {
                $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                  height:400,
                  width:500,
                  modal: true,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  open: function(event, ui) {  
                    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none");  

                }
                });

                $( "#openerP2" ).click(function() {
                $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                  $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
                $( "#buttonP2" ).click(function() {
                  $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog( "close" );
                });
              });
            $(function(){$("#dialogP2").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();});

            $(function() {
                $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                  height:400,
                  width:500,
                  modal: true,
                  autoOpen: false,
                  open: function(event, ui) {  
                    $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none");  

                }
                });

                $( "#openerP3" ).click(function() {
                $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                  $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog( "open" );
                });
                $( "#buttonP3" ).click(function() {
                  $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog( "close" );
                });
              });
            $(function(){$("#dialogP3").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();});
            });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gostaria de saber como posso passar o id do botao clicado e a partir
>   dele fazer um if e executar o procedimento.

Utilize uma classe nos seus botões. Exemplo: classe 'botoes'. Você só vai precisar chamá-lo uma vez e vai passar o id dele para a função (uma função apenas).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $(".botao").click(function() {
        getValueUsingClass($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    function getValueUsingClass(idBotao){
        var chkArray = [];

        $(".chk:checked").each(function() {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });                 

        alert(idBotao);

        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join('') + "";

        if(selected.length > 1){
            if(chkArray.length > 1){
            alert("Selecione um campo");
            $('input[id=TP_ACO_P]').val("");
            }else{  
            $('input[id=TP_ACO_P]').val(selected);}
        }else{
            alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");  
        }
        $('input[id=buscar]').val("");
    }

    $(function() {
        $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:400,
            width:500,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {  
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none"); 
            }
        });

        $( "#openerP1" ).click(function() {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
            $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

        $( "#buttonP1" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogP1" ).dialog( "close" );
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#dialogP1").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:400,
            width:500,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {  
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none"); 
            }
        });

        $( "#openerP2" ).click(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
            $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
        $( "#buttonP2" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogP2" ).dialog( "close" );
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#dialogP2").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
    });

    $(function() {
        $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height:400,
            width:500,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function(event, ui) {  
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none"); 
            }
        });

        $( "#openerP3" ).click(function() {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
            $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog( "open" );
        });

        $( "#buttonP3" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialogP3" ).dialog( "close" );
        });
    });

    $(function(){
        $("#dialogP3").dialog().parents(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: A questão do if eu não entendi muito bem. Pode tentar ser mais claro pra eu implementar a resposta?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta,esta funcionando corretamente.

Comment: Só mais uma duvida, eu consigo fazer isso para os dialogs também?

Comment: Opa, ja consegui, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Por acaso você já chegou a testar o seletor jQuery por classe? Você pode definir nomes específicos das classes que deseja que tenha as funções atreladas e utilizá-las como seletor, veja:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#buttonP1").click(function () { getValueUsingClass("TP_ACO_P"); });
    $("#buttonP2").click(function () { getValueUsingClass("ACAB_P"); });
    $("#buttonP3").click(function () { getValueUsingClass("TT_P"); });

    function getValueUsingClass(id) {
        /* declare an checkbox array */
        var chkArray = [];
        /* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
        $(".chk:checked").each(function () {
            chkArray.push($(this).val());
        });
        var teste = $(this).id;
        alert(teste);
        /* we join the array separated by the comma */
        var selected;
        selected = chkArray.join('') + "";

        /* check if there is selected checkboxes, by default the length is 1 as it contains one single comma */
        if (selected.length > 1) {
            if (chkArray.length > 1) {
                alert("Selecione um campo");
                $('input[id=' + id + ']').val("");
            } else {
                $('input[id=' + id + ']').val(selected);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Nenhuma dado selecionado");
        }
        $('input[id=buscar]').val("");
    }

    $(function () {
        $(".dialog").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 400,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').display("none");

            }
        });
        $(".opener").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
            $(".dialog").dialog("open");

        });
        $(".button").click(function () {
            $(".dialog").dialog("close");
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Talvez esta não seja a solução, mas pode te encaminhar para ela.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, está funcionando corretamente agora.